# Application prints duplicate element Python

Tags: python

I want the write an application that can print out all the questions from a list. But not sure what is wrong with my code, the list does not print out in incremental order. Instead it goes from 0,0,1,0,1,2. I don't understand why it has to reprint the previous element. I expect the list to print out like 0,1,2,3 ... I know there is another alternative to get the result I want, but I want to understand what I did wrong. I am a newbie, any help is appreciated!

question_model.py

```
class Question:
    def __init__(self, text, answer):
        self.text = text
        self.answer = answer
```

quiz_brain.py

```
class QuizBrain:
    def __init__(self,questions_list):
        self.question_number = 0
        self.questions_list = questions_list
        self.number_of_question = len(questions_list)



    def next_question(self):
        current_question = self.questions_list[self.question_number]
        input(f"{self.question_number}:{current_question.text} (True/False): ")
        self.question_number += 1


    def still_has_questions(self):
        while self.question_number < self.number_of_question-1:
            self.next_question()
```

data.py

```
question_data = [
    {"text": "A slug's blood is green.", "answer": "True"},
    {"text": "The loudest animal is the African Elephant.", "answer": "False"},
    {"text": "Approximately one quarter of human bones are in the feet.", "answer": "True"},
    {"text": "The total surface area of a human lungs is the size of a football pitch.", "answer": "True"},
    {"text": "In West Virginia, USA, if you accidentally hit an animal with your car, you are free to take it home to eat.", "answer": "True"},
    {"text": "In London, UK, if you happen to die in the House of Parliament, you are entitled to a state funeral.", "answer": "False"},
    {"text": "It is illegal to pee in the Ocean in Portugal.", "answer": "True"},
    {"text": "You can lead a cow down stairs but not up stairs.", "answer": "False"},
    {"text": "Google was originally called 'Backrub'.", "answer": "True"},
    {"text": "Buzz Aldrin's mother's maiden name was 'Moon'.", "answer": "True"},
    {"text": "No piece of square dry paper can be folded in half more than 7 times.", "answer": "False"},
    {"text": "A few ounces of chocolate can to kill a small dog.", "answer": "True"}
]
```

main.py

```
from question_model import Question
from data import question_data
from quiz_brain import QuizBrain




question_bank = []

for i in question_data:
    question_text = i["text"]
    question_answer = i["text"]
    new_question = Question(question_text,question_answer)
    question_bank.append(new_question)

    quiz = QuizBrain(question_bank) #create the new quiz object
    quiz.still_has_questions()
```

Comment: Could you also share.. how are you calling the class `QuizBrain`?

Comment: You can convert the list to a set (Sets do not allow duplicate members.) Then convert back to list and order in ascending.

Comment: `def number_of_questions(self): return len(self.questions_list)`  and `def still_has_questions(self): for idx,q in enumerate(self.questions_list): self.next_question(idx)` and use the idx  (or idx+1) for your output - that way you get rid of 2 members and your counting problem.

Answer (score 0):

It works properly:

```py
class QuizBrain:
    def __init__(self, questions_list):
        self.question_number = 0
        self.questions_list = questions_list
        self.number_of_question = len(questions_list)

    def next_question(self):
        current_question = self.questions_list[self.question_number]
        input(f"{self.question_number}:{current_question} (True/False): ")
        self.question_number += 1

    def still_has_questions(self):
        while self.question_number <= self.number_of_question - 1:
            self.next_question()


quest = QuizBrain(['first question', 'second question', 'third question'])
quest.still_has_questions()
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, it would be useful to know how you're calling the class.
Why are you using current_question.text? What are you trying to pass when creating the object?
Anyway, keeping your code basically as it is (just drop the -1 in the while condition, and pass a list of strings as questions), you could do something like:

```
class QuizBrain:
    def __init__(self, questions_list):
        self.question_number = 0
        self.questions_list = questions_list
        self.number_of_question = len(questions_list)

    def next_question(self):
        current_question = self.questions_list[self.question_number]
        input(f"{self.question_number}:{current_question} (True/False): ")
        self.question_number += 1

    def still_has_questions(self):
        while self.question_number < self.number_of_question:
            self.next_question()


quest = QuizBrain(['question 1', 'question 2', 'question 3'])
quest.still_has_questions()
```

Or you could simplify it a little:

```
class QuizBrain:
    def __init__(self, questions_list):
        self.questions_list = questions_list


    def ask_questions_until_end(self):
        for index, question in enumerate(self.questions_list):
            input(f"{index}: {question} (True/False): ")


quiz = QuizBrain(['question 1', 'question 2', 'question 3'])
quiz.ask_questions_until_end()
```